# The '<' operator is reserved for future use (PowerShell script from command line)

Tags: powershell, command, command-line-arguments, command-prompt, powershell-1.0

I am trying to run the powershell script from the command line along with the arguments but it is always failing with the below error. Can anyone help?

```
cmd /c "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\start.ps1 -settings_override_xml /"<?xml version=/'1.0/'?><Settings><Keys>243</Keys></Settings>/""
```

Error:

```
< was unexpected at this time
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the double quotes in the middle with a backtick.

```
cmd /c "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\start.ps1 -settings_override_xml /`"<?xml version=/'1.0/'?><Settings><Keys>243</Keys></Settings>/`""
```

**Edit:** To explain, it was reading your original command as:

Start command prompt with the command:

```
cmd /c "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\start.ps1 -settings_override_xml /"
```

Then import the following as arguments or input for that command:

```
<?xml version=/'1.0/'?><Settings><Keys>243</Keys></Settings>/""
```

Hm, you're right, it's erroring on the < which is a reserved character, and I'm betting it'll error on > as well. Escape those and it should work.

```
cmd /c 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\start.ps1 -settings_override_xml /"`<?xml version=/''1.0/''?`>`<Settings`>`<Keys`>243`</Keys`>`</Settings`>/"'
```

Tested that as working on my machine with no errors given.

Comment: I did try the backtick before the double quote,, still the same error.

Comment: Try the updated line (last code formatted line) in my answer and see if that works better for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I tried the escape on all the special chars,,, Now its a different error, "The system cannot find the file specified.." The file location is correct, I am 100% positive

Comment: Are you able to do a simple `cmd /c 'Powershell.exe c:\start.ps1'`?

Comment: Yes, I am able to run the above command. The problem is with the XML string,,, Its somehow not liking it

Comment: Did you change the enclosing quotes to single quotes and double single quote the internal single quotes like I had?